# Write to a csv file multiple times?

Tags: python, csv, overwrite

is there a kind of an "a" mode like when write to a txt.-file multiple times for csv? My code always overrides the csv each time, when executed.

```
import csv

row = ['2', 'Marie', 'California']



with open('test_CSV.csv', 'w') as writeFile: #File darf nicht offen in excel sein, sonst keine permission
    writer = csv.writer(writeFile)
    writer.writerow(row)

#readFile.close()
writeFile.close()
```

Comment: Just use `a` mode when opening the file.

Comment: Oh man, i works well. Thanks.